# Why is Android closing the application without showing the "<application> has stopped unexpectedly" message?

Tags: android, debugging

I am in the process of learning Android development and was trying to crash my application at runtime. I made a button that calls a method when clicked and then made sure that the method does not exist.

The application starts up fine. As soon as i click the button, the application closes just as intended. The only unexpected thing was that my device did not show any error message like application has closed unexpectedly or that the application force closed.

Did I accidentally turn off some setting in the Developer Options or is it just my device that doesn't like showing error messages ? Any more information needed ?

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="$0"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrders(View view) {
        int quantity = 5 ;
        display(quantity) ;
        displayPrice(quantity * 50) ;
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displayPrice(int number) {
       TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
        priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> 01-20 16:08:54.087 28870-28893/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4 01-20 16:08:54.087 28870-28893/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap
>   behavior 1 01-20 16:08:58.044 28870-28870/com.example.android.justjava
>   V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b82000f 01-20 16:08:58.119
>   28870-28870/com.example.android.justjava D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 01-20 16:08:58.120 28870-28870/com.example.android.justjava
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 28870
>                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   submitOrder(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5642)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22338)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 01-20
>   16:08:58.120 28870-28870/com.example.android.justjava D/AppTracker:
>   App Event: crash 01-20 16:08:58.132 28870-28870/? I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 28870 SIG: 9

It's based on [this](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud836/lessons/4038208680/concepts/42807051900923) Udacity course.

Comment: where is ur logcat and code ?

Comment: @W4R10CK Updated the question.

Comment: try to produce Index Out Of Bounds Exception and see if same thing happens

Comment: @Eswar Tried that. logcat shows IndexOutOfBounds Exception but the app still exits without any force close message. New Logcat here --> http://pastebin.com/VZ3RYKqJ

Comment: @adeen-s what is your device model and Android version

Comment: @Eswar Oneplus 3 Running open beta 10. Android 7.0  https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/oxygenos-open-beta-10-n-for-oneplus-3.482108/

Answer (score 0):

In your XML button, its `submitOrder` not `submitOrders`. See the extra `S` :

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="ORDER"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
```

So, change this:

```
public void submitOrders(View view) {
```

With this:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
```

Comment: That is done on purpose. That is not what i need an answer to. Please read the question again.

Comment: because it's not crash it's an error/ exception. which is not handled.

Comment: Isn't a crash by definition supposed to be when the application exits due to an error/exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove s from method name    submitOrders

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
        int quantity = 5 ;
        display(quantity) ;
        displayPrice(quantity * 50) ;
    }
```

Or  You can remove  a`ndroid:onClick="submitOrder"`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="ORDER"/>
```

than in your java file

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        Button order = (Button)findViewById(R.id.order);
        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               int quantity = 5 ;
               display(quantity) ;
               displayPrice(quantity * 50) ;
           }
        });
  }
```

Comment: My question is not about the error produced. it is about the lack of an error message on my device.